# Sequence $0\leq a_{n}-l\leq \dfrac{\pi^{2} }{2^{2n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let for $n\geq 2\quad a_{n}=\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{k}}\right)$ and
>    $b_{n}=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$ and let  $c_{n}=a_{n}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$
>
> - Show $(a_n)$ is bounded and decreasing $(b_n)$ is increasing and studying$(C_n)_{n}$
> - Deduce the value of the limit $l$ town of  $a_n$ and $b_n$
> - Show that $0\leq a_{n}-l\leq \dfrac{\pi^{2} }{2^{2n+1}}$ (note that: $|1-\cos x|\leq \dfrac{x^{2}}{2})$

The original of text

[image]

For 1 
$a_n$ is decreasing :

let  $u_n=u_{n-1}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^n})\quad \forall n\geq 3$
we got  $u_{n-1}-u_n=(1-cos(\frac{\pi}{2^n})u_{n-1}$ which is positive since product of two numbers.

Bounded:

Let $n \geq 2$. we've $\cos a \geq 0$ when $a\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. since $ \frac{\pi}{2^k}\in [0,2]$ for all $k\in \{{2,\ldots,n}\},\ u_n$ is product $n-1$ positive number.
is positive.

$b_n$ is increasing:

Let $(v_n)u_n \sin({\pi}{2^n})$

the last question which is important

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If I were you, I'd use: $\sin(2u) = 2\sin(u)\cos(u)$ with u = $\frac{\pi}{2^n}$; that might give you a more useful formula for $(a_n)$. In fact you can calculate the value of $c_n$ using this. Look at the last term of the product and see if you can find a recurrence somewhere.

**Edit:**

More precisely: $c_n = a_n*\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n}) =\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^n})*\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})*\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n-1}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{k}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2*\frac{\pi}{2^n})*a_{n-1} $

$\implies c_n = \frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}})a_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}c_{n-1}$

$\implies c_n = \frac{c_2}{2^{n-2}}$ (geometrical sequence)

Hence you get: $$a_n = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})}$$

Comment: if you just could give more details with formula not with words to upvote ur post

Comment: @Educ Ok, I didn't want to spoil you the pleasure of finding this on your own :)

Comment: But now you spoiled it. Why?

Comment: @Did Because there is not middle steps. I did not see how I could be more precise without giving him this. However the answer is not complete, he still has to prove his statements. Was I wrong? The part from "More precisely..." to the end was not here at first..

Comment: i can't get ur point after i got the expression of $a_n$ how can that help me to show $0\leq a_{n}-l\leq \dfrac{\pi^{2} }{2^{2n+1}}$ and my try is correct for question 1

Comment: @Educ just so you know I'm french (I say this because of the original text) so if you want to talk in french in private it's possible :)
As for your question, are you familiar with limited expansions (développements limités) ? You have the result: $\sin(u) = u + o(u)$ when $u \rightarrow 0$, use it to get "l", and then you can look for your inequality using (for instance) : $u - \frac{u^3}{6} \leq \sin(u) \leq u $ or the one given (haven't tried it but fiddling with it should do the trick, will try it later).