# An inequality for the product $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\cos\frac{\pi }{2^{k}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, products

I have this hint from old question of mine if someone could help me to understand it

[Sequence $0\leq a_{n}-l\leq \dfrac{\pi^{2} }{2^{2n+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070730/sequence-0-leq-a-n-l-leq-dfrac-pi2-22n1)

for the first question it's easy to see that a_n is decreasing :

note that $ \forall x\in [0,\pi/2],\quad \cos(x) \geq 0$
since $\pi/2^n \in [0,\pi/2]$ then $\cos(\pi/2)\geq 0$ then $a_n\geq 0  $

let $a_n=a_{n−1}\cos(\pi2n)\quad  \forall n\geq 3$

then  $a_{n+1}−a_n=u_n(cos(\pi/2^n)-1)$ which is negative since $(cos(\pi/2^n)-1)$ its.

but for bounded :

we've already that $a_n\geq 0,\quad \forall n \geq 2$

note that $|(cos(\pi/2^k)|\leq 1\quad \forall k\geq 2$ then $\prod_{k=3}^{n}|(cos(\pi/2^k)|\leq 1 $ thus $0\leq a_n \leq 1$

for $b_{n}=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$ is increasing

$b_{n+1}-b_{n}=a_{n+1}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n+1}}\right)-a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n+1}}\right)-a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$

or $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\cos(\pi/2^{n+1})$

im stuck here and after we show $b_n$ is increasing is that can help us to study $c_n$

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you want to show that 

$$a_{n}
=\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{k}}\right)=
\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}$$

Comment: Why don't you ask this in your old question itself?

Comment: @first if you could please check my answers and tell me if im right and then help me where im got stuck

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^k}\right)=\dfrac{\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}\right)}{2\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^k}\right)}$. Now let $k$ runs from $2$ to $n$ and simplify the product.

Comment: this hint for which question

Comment: @Educ: $\phantom{}$ yours.

Comment: of cours mine but i have 3 which one of them