# $b_{n}$ is increasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think there is misunderstanding in my last post because its contain three questions so i will post question by question step by step

[An inequality for the product $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\cos\frac{\pi }{2^{k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079962/an-inequality-for-the-product-prod-k-2n-cos-frac-pi-2k/1079988?noredirect=1#comment2197949_1079988)

> Let $n\geq 2\quad a_{n}=\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{k}}\right)$ and $b_{n}=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$

Show that $b_{n}$ is increasing

my attempts :

- $b_{n+1}-b_{n}=a_{n+1}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n+1}}\right)-a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n+1}}\right)-a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$
- $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\cos(\pi/2^{n+1})$

im stuck here in these two ways

any help would be appreciated

Comment: just see my update, guz=because

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\dfrac{\cos^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}{\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1+\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{2}}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}=\dfrac{1+\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{2\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}>\dfrac{2\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{2\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}=1$.

Comment: but $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}\cos(\pi/2^{n+1})}{a_n\cos(\pi/2^{n})}=cos(π/2n+1)$ am i right

Comment: No, the first $n$ terms of the product cancel out and you're left with what I wrote above. Try writing it out.

Answer (score 2):

A variant: $$\begin{align*} b_n <b_{n+1} &\iff \cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\Bigr) < \cos^2\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\Bigr)\\ &\iff 2\cos^2\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\Bigr)-1 < \cos^2\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\Bigr)\\ &\iff \cos^2\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\Bigr) <1 .\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems easy to prove the opposite. $a_2 =  \cos{\frac{\pi{}}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
Then, $\forall \ n > 2, 0 \lt \cos{\frac{\pi{}}{2^n}} \lt 1 $ so therefore $ b_n $ is strictly decreasing.

Edit: Ah, nevermind I get it.

Comment: The sequence claimed to be increasing is $(b_n)$.