# $a_n$ is bounded and decreasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

my second question from

[[An inequality for the product $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\cos\frac{\pi }{2^{k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079962/an-inequality-for-the-product-prod-k-2n-cos-frac-pi-2k/1079988?noredirect=1#comment2197949_1079988][1])

> Let $n\geq 2\quad a_{n}=\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{k}}\right)$ and $b_{n}=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$

Show that $a_{n}$ is decreasing and bounded

note that $ \forall x\in [0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}],\quad \cos(x) \geq 0$
since $\pi/2^n \in [0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$ then $cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2})\geq 0$ then $a_n\geq 0  $

let $a_n=a_{n−1}\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n})\quad  \forall n\geq 3$

then  $a_{n+1}−a_n=a_n(\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}})-1)$ which is negative since $(\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}})-1)$ its.

but for bounded :

we've already that $a_n\geq 0,\quad \forall n \geq 2$

note that $|(cos(\pi/2^k)|\leq 1\quad \forall k\geq 2$ then $\prod_{k=3}^{n}|(cos(\pi/2^k)|\leq 1 $ thus $0\leq a_n \leq 1$

am i right ?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning about $a_n$ decreasing is fine; that is, for $n\ge2$, $0\lt\cos\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)\lt1$. This also shows that $a_n\gt0$. However, we can do a bit better.

**Trigonometric Approach**

Since
$$
2\sin\left(\frac\pi{2^k}\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi{2^k}\right)
=\sin\left(\frac\pi{2^{k-1}}\right)
$$
We have
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n\cos\left(\frac\pi{2^k}\right)=\frac2{2^n\sin\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{2^n\sin\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)}=\frac2\pi
$$
Therefore, $a_n\gt\frac2\pi$.

---

**Another Approach**

Since $\sin(x)\le x$, $\cos(x)\ge\left(1-x^2\right)^{1/2}\ge\left(1-x^2\right)$. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=2}^\infty\cos\left(\frac\pi{2^k}\right)
&\ge\prod_{k=2}^\infty\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{4^k}\right)\\
&=\prod_{k=2}^\infty\left(1+\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{4^k}}{1-\frac{\pi^2}{4^k}}\right)^{-1}\\
&\ge\exp\left(\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{4^k}}{1-\frac{\pi^2}{4^k}}\right)^{-1}\\
&\ge\exp\left(\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{4^k}}{1-\frac{\pi^2}{16}}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{-4\pi^2}{48-3\pi^2}\right)\\[9pt]
&\doteq0.116881538733185
\end{align}
$$

Comment: could you see that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080152/0-leq-a-n-l-leq-dfrac-pi2-22n1

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. Also, you can deduce that from the fact that, since $(a_n)$ is decreasing, $a_n\le a_2$ for every $n\ge2$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n \leq 1,\forall n \geq 2$.