# the limits of $a_n $and $b_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

this is related to that one [$a_n$ is bounded and decreasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080042/a-n-is-bounded-and-decreasing/1080080#1080080)

> Let for $n\geq 2\quad a_{n}=\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{k}}\right)$ and
>    $b_{n}=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$ and let  $c_{n}=a_{n}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$

Deduce the value of the limits of $a_n, b_n$, and $c_n$.

Comment: You literally linked to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Notice that

$$\cos\left(\frac \pi{2^k}\right)=\frac12\frac{\sin\left(\frac \pi{2^{k-1}}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac \pi{2^k}\right)}$$
and telescope.

Comment: Thanks but i was working from the morning i can't take hint if possible details

Comment: So leave it for tomorrow;-)

Comment: but i need it now

Answer (score 0):

From a related post and its solution, $a_n \to \dfrac{2}{\pi} \Rightarrow b_n \to \dfrac{2}{\pi}$ as well. Plus $c_n \to 0$.