# $0\leq a_{n}-l\leq \dfrac{\pi^{2} }{2^{2n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

this is related to that one [the limits of $a_n $and $b_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080094/the-limits-of-a-n-and-b-n?noredirect=1#comment2198229_1080094)

> Let for $n\geq 2\quad a_{n}=\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{k}}\right)$ and
>    $b_{n}=a_{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$ and let  $c_{n}=a_{n}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi }{2^{n}}\right)$

Show that $0\leq a_{n}-l\leq \dfrac{\pi^{2} }{2^{2n+1}}$ (note that: $|1-\cos x|\leq \dfrac{x^{2}}{2})$

can we say that $$b_n < l < a_n$$
Then $$  0 < a_n-l< a_n-b_n$$

$$a_n- b_n = a_n(1-\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n})$$

since $|a_n|\leq 1$  and $1-\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n})\leq \dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} $

am i right

Comment: I think its right......but you need to square the $\pi$, and double the $n$.

Comment: $\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\leq \dfrac{\pi^2}{2^{n+1}}$ then

Comment: but i need to add something to make me sure to say that we've $b_n < l < a_n$

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1080080),
$$
a_n=\frac2{2^n\sin\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)}
$$
therefore
$$
b_n=\frac2{2^n\tan\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)}
$$
It is also shown that
$$
l=\frac2\pi
$$

Furthermore, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151), for $|x|\lt\frac\pi2$,
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le1\le\frac{\tan(x)}{x}
$$
which implies that
$$
b_n\le\frac2\pi\le a_n
$$
and that
$$
1-\cos(x)\le\frac{x^2}2
$$
therefore
$$
1-\cos\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)\le\frac{\pi^2}{2^{2n+1}}
$$
So you are correct, but there are better bounds for $1-\cos(x)$.

Comment: thanks so much just give me moment to read what you wrote